# Как работает RayCast с Prefab в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Я сделал префаб (модель танка). Потом навесил на него скрипт, где написал прстой код для тестирования RayCast:

```
Ray visionRay = new Ray(this.gameObject.transform.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
if (visionRay, out hit)
{
    print("hit " + thit.colliser.ganeObject.name);
}
```

// Этот скрипт должен выводить в консоль имя объекта в который попал луч

Но это не работает, точнее работает не так как бы мне этого хотелось, выводится в консоль имя одно и того же объекта, раз за разом, как бы я не поворачивал и не двигал модель.

С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Comment: Что за "thit, Gane Object, colliser " это что вообще такое

Comment: Хотел бы я посмотреть, как этот код хоть что-то выводит...